# how to load everything when opening a saved notebook

Tags: notebooks

generally, when I carry over work in a notebook from the previous day, I have to physically start from the top and re-evaluate every statement before I can begin from where i left off. Is there any setting I can enable so that the notebook will be in state when it becomes active? 
    Thanks,
    Sid.

Comment: No. But you can do: DumpSave["today.mx", "Global`*"] and then load it the next day by Get@"today.mx"

Comment: Well, thanks. I have not tried this yet. Actually, this happens also if I leave Mathematica (not quit i.e) for some time and work on other things, and then get back to it. Have others also observed this? I just checked that the "Dynamic updating enabled" menu item was checked, so probably there must be some other setting that can achieve this, in addition to Rolf's answer.

Comment: The definitions and variables are not associated with the *notebook*.  The notebook merely holds some code that can be used to create these definitions.  Rolf's answer is the partial workaround.  If you had packages loaded, you'll still need to re-load them.

Comment: @Sid could you upload a notebook somewhere so we can try ourselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Based on Rolf's and Szabolcs's comments)

The definitions and variables created during evaluation are not associated with a particular notebook: they are stored in the memory. The notebook merely holds some code that can be used to create these definitions.

You can save all the definition defined in the `` "Global`" `` context by `DumpSave` and then load them the next day by `Get`:

```
DumpSave["today.mx", "Global`*"]

Get@"today.mx"
```

If you want the `Get` code to be evaluated every time you start the kernel, put the above line into the file:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]
```

This, however, is only a partial workaround: it does not save any definition from other user-modified namespaces than `` "Global`" `` - though it is easy to extend it to other modified contexts if their names are known. Also, if you had packages loaded, it's easier to simply re-load them at the start of your session than to `DumpSave` their states at the end of the day.